# Replacing a dynamically generated images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How do I replace a dynamic image that is generated by a loop?**

### [image]

The above image should look like this in html rendered by `mustache` templating system.

```
{{#images}}

<div class="picture-caption">
    <img id="{{id}}" class="caption" src="./data/picture_caption/{{picture_caption}}" alt="your image" />
    <input id="image-value" data-id="{{id}}" class="image-box-{{id}}" type="file" style="display: none;" value="
{{picture_caption}}" />{{id}}
</div>

{{/answers}}
```

I did coding and worked out only changing for the first index in the loop (which is the son guko image)

```
function readURL(input, caption_id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#"+caption_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".caption").click(function(e) {
    var caption_id = $(this).attr('id');
    // console.log(caption_id);
    $(".image-box-"+caption_id).click();
});

$("#image-value").change(function(e){
    var caption_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // alert(caption_id);
    readURL(this, caption_id);
});
```

Any ideas/alternatives I can do to implement this?

Comment: When you alerted the caption_id, did it got the correct value you where expecting?

Comment: yes it did @AdrianDelaPiedra

Comment: Oh i see, then the problem lies in the #image-value id i guess. I'll check this out with fiddle.

Comment: turns out, I just needed to change the tagging id of my `jquery onchange` to $('[id="image-value"]') from $("#image-value"). dont know why but syntax worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple input elements with same id (`id="image-value"`) that's why jQuery picks up only the first of them when executing onchange handler you binded here -  `$("#image-value").change(function(e){...})`.

So replace `$("#image-value").change(function(e){...})` to `$('[type="file"]').change(function(e){...})` like below to attach event handler to all input elements.

Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/dm7qvza8/).

```
function readURL(input, caption_id) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#"+caption_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".caption").click(function() {
    $(".image-box-"+this.id).click();
});

$('[type="file"]').change(function(e){
    var caption_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    readURL(this, caption_id);
});
```

Instead of `[type="file"]` you could use a class selector. For that you could:

1. add an extra class to all inputs like `class="image-box-{{id}} your-class"` and then use it like `$('.your-class').change(function(e){...})`

or

2. maybe just shorten what you have to `class="image-box"`, because there is no reason to attach individual class to every single element, and use it like `$('.image-box').change(function(e){...})`.

And I would remove `id="image-value"` repeated for every element to avoid potential errors in the future or change to `id="image-value-{{id}}"`.

Comment: this could have been a simplified answer but there is something wrong as it doesnt change the image onload

Comment: very similar to mine but worked perfectly. can i use different attribute other than type here?

Comment: Yes, you were almost there! I added some thoughts about other selectors to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This event is only registered on the first element that have this id.

```
$("#image-value").change(function(e){
    var caption_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // alert(caption_id);
    readURL(this, caption_id);
});
```

That's why it only fires in the first picture. You can change it to .image-value to make it as a class and then in your html add the image-value as class like:

```
{{#images}}

<div class="picture-caption">
    <img id="{{id}}" class="caption" src="./data/picture_caption/{{picture_caption}}" alt="your image" />
    <input data-id="{{id}}" class="image-value image-box-{{id}}" type="file" style="display: none;" value="
{{picture_caption}}" />{{id}}
</div>

{{/answers}}
```

script:

```
$(".image-value").change(function(e){
    var caption_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // alert(caption_id);
    readURL(this, caption_id);
});
```

I made the freedom to remove the id attribute because it will cause multiple same ids.

Comment: turns out, I just needed to change the tagging id of my jquery `onchange` to $('[id="image-value"]') from $("#image-value"). dont know why but syntax worked perfectly

Comment: that can be done also, it works because $('[id="image-value"]') returns the list of elements having that attribute and value it's syntax would be like this $("[attr='value']"), while on the otherhand $("#image-value") restricts to selecting only the first element have that id.
But for future development, refrain from using same id's on your elements though, it will just cause uproar ;)